# How to create Stream object directly from Image stored in Data Table?

Tags: c#, stream

I am creating Stream object by first writing image on hard disk then creating stream object from its path.

```
System.Drawing.Image im = (System.Drawing.Image)rw[3];     //rw is row of data table

im.Save("D:\\aaa.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

System.IO.Stream st = System.IO.File.OpenRead("D:\\aaa.jpg");
```

This is not efficient way to achieve this.. Is there any way so that i can create stream object directly from image stored in data table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `MemoryStream`:

```
System.Drawing.Image image = (System.Drawing.Image)rw[3];
using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: Thanx for response but MemoryStream will not work as i have to pass it to another method which updates gmail profile pic and that method only accepts Stream class object.

Comment: @zaino: have you tried it? Actually a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) _is_ a `System.IO.Stream` since it inherits directly from it. Otherwise [`Image.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms142147(v=vs.110).aspx) would also not work.

Comment: GDataRequestException was caught during calling ContactRequest.setPhoto(Contact, Stream); (cr.setPhoto(gmailC,memoryStream);)  why this method throws exception on memoryStream ?

Comment: @zaino: i have never used it but maybe you need a bitmap, so try `ImageFormat.Bmp`. Have a look here and search for `MemoryStream` and `_googleService.SetPhoto`: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=29103226